# Where does python ggplot take its default values from

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

Where does python ggplot take its default values from and how can one change them so that there is no need to use `+ theme_whatever()` every time a plot is created?

Comment: I added a bugreport for this: https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/396. Until then the answer below is the only workaround. :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the `ggplot` package from http://ggplot.yhathq.com/? There does not seem to be any equivalent to the `theme_set` function of the `ggplot2` R package, the default theme is currently hardcoded to be `theme_grey()`. I think the best you can do is to define your theme in one place and use it in all plots:

```
from ggplot import *
my_theme = theme_seaborn()
p = ggplot(aes(x='wt', y='mpg'), data=mtcars) + geom_point()
print(p + my_theme)
p2 = ggplot(aes(x='date', ymin='beef - 1000',
            ymax='beef + 1000'), data=meat) + geom_area()
print(p2 + my_theme)
```

Alternatively, you can define yourself a small wrapper function that you call instead of the `print(... + my_theme)` call.